# Jquery shoutbox IE error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hey I have some jquery/ajax code for a shoutbox and the problem I am having is that in IE when I had the form tags around the input message and submit button in the html code, upon pressing the enter key in the message box it was reloading the page, this was not occuring in other browsers, so I removed the form because it was not needed, and the enter key is now submitting the message in IE but not in chrome or firefox. Is there a way I can have both an onclick event and enter event together to correct this? at the moment once the button is clicked the button is disabled for 2 seconds and then renabled, I need this to also happen if the enter button is pressed.

I know I have a lot of inline css for the shoutout box but its just a testing version at the moment, I will tidy that up once its completed.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
I had the form tag like so 
<form method="POST" action=""/>

    <div id="shoutout" style="position:absolute; height:auto; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden; float:right; right:10px; background-color:#121212; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:14px; width:305px; padding-left:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-bottom:1px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
         <h2>Shout Out!</h2>                
                <strong>Message:</strong>
                <input type="text" id="message" name="message"/>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <div id="messagecontainer" style="position:relative; height:240px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; background-color:#F5F5F5; color: #F6221D; font-size:12px; width:305px; margin-top:5px;">
        <div id="shoutmessages" style="position:relative; word-wrap: break-word; padding-left:5px; width:auto; height:auto; overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:hidden;"> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

//JQUERY AJAX CODE BELOW

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

refresh_shoutbox();
setInterval("refresh_shoutbox()", 10000);

var running = false;

$("#message").keypress(function(e){ 
    if (e.which == 13 && running === true){ 
        return false; 
    } 
}); 

 $("#submit").click(function(){
    if ($("#message").val() != ''){
        running = true;
        $("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
        setTimeout(function(){  
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled")
        running = false;
        }, 2000);
        }else{                  
        return false;
        }

     var name = $("#name").val();
     var message = $("#message").val();
     var data = 'name=' + name + '&message=' + message;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "shout.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
            $("#shoutmessages").slideToggle(0, function(){
            $(this).html(html).slideToggle(0);
            $("#message").val("");
            });
        }
    });    
    return false;       
});
});

function refresh_shoutbox(){
    var data = 'refresh=1';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "shout.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
        $("#shoutmessages").html(html);
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all this is done via AJAX anyway, you may find it easier just to not include the `<form>` element at all.

That way, you avoid all of the annoying browser-specific behaviors that occur with form elements in a `<form>`- like automatically submitting forms if a `<button>` is pressed.

You said when you removed it in the other browsers, the enter key didn't work- did you receive any errors from the Chrome or Safari JS debug console, for example?

Comment: well for some reason, in IE and chrome and firefox, I cant submit the message by pressing the enter key, only by clicking on the submit button, I thought it was working in IE but the enter key is not working in any of them actually. Nope no errors from those either.

Comment: Well in your code, when the enter key is pressed, you instruct it to `return false; `, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: thats only if the button is disabled will it return false because because var running will be set to true.

Comment: I know. But why would the enter key work, if they only code that runs when it is pressed does `return false;`? You should keep that, and add in code to call `$("#submit").click()`.

Comment: ah ok thanks, sorry I'm quite new to Jquery how would I go about that??.

Comment: No problem- just put in `$("#submit").click()`.